# PHP upload an image file through get url

Tags: php

$file = "http://localhost/Project/SmartInventory/sims/simsLIB/barcode.php?codetype=Code128&size=$imgsize&sizefactor=1.2&text=$barcode&print=true&extraTxt=MRP: $mrp&extraTxt1= $product";

```
// Open the file to get existing content
$data = file_get_contents($file);

// New file
$new = '../../../images/barcode/new.png';

// Write the contents back to a new file
file_put_contents($new, $data);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you have a question?

Comment: Please provide us your question, with as much detail as possible. Is seems that you have only provided us your code.